# Shared folders don't get linked the second time on a VM

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm using virtualbox v `4.2.8r83876` and Vagrant v `1.2.2`. I packaged my box using `vagrant box package`. Now I want to bring it up again. My `Vagrantfile` contains a line to sync folders, like so:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/some/dir/on/host", "/var/www/apps/some_project/current", :extra => "dmode=777,fmode=777"
```

This worked the first time I had brought the VM up with `vagrant up`. The second time however, `/var/www/apps/some_project/current` just isn't there! `vagrant up` doesn't give me an error either:

```
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
```

And if I inspect the VM through Virtualbox, sure enough, it shows me that I have a shared folder configured. But it doesn't exist in the VM! What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` fixed this issue for me.